# SwiftUI Table reorder columns - macOS

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, tableview

Is it possible to reorder columns in SwiftUI Tables using Drag and Drop?

Apple has introduced "Table" in SwiftUI 3.0 in summer 2021. It's the SwiftUI equivalent of NSTableView.
I was not able to find any hints in apples documentation regarding column reordering.

I'm speaking of reordering as we all know from NSTableViews like the one in Finder.
[image]

I used the sample code provided by Apple.

```
struct Person: Identifiable {
    let givenName: String
    let familyName: String
    let id = UUID()
}


@State private var people = [
    Person(givenName: "Juan", familyName: "Chavez"),
    Person(givenName: "Mei", familyName: "Chen"),
    Person(givenName: "Tom", familyName: "Clark"),
    Person(givenName: "Gita", familyName: "Kumar"),
]

var body: some View {
    Table(people, selection: $selectedPeople, sortOrder: $sortOrder) {
        TableColumn("Given Name", value: \.givenName)
        TableColumn("Family Name", value: \.familyName)
    }
}
```

I also tried to build the table columns dynamically with for each. but that throws a bunch of debug errors.

```
@State private var columns = [
    TableColumn("Given Name", value: \Person.givenName),
    TableColumn("Family Name", value: \Person.familyName)
]

var body: some View {
    Table(people, selection: $selectedPeople, sortOrder: $sortOrder) {
            
        ForEach (columns, id: \.self) { column in
            column
        }
        
    }
}
```

Seems like ForEach is not compatible with TableColumns:

> Generic struct 'Table' requires that 'ForEach<[TableColumn<Person, Never, Text, Text>], TableColumn<Person, Never, Text, Text>, some AccessibilityRotorContent>' conform to 'TableColumnContent'

> Static method 'buildBlock' requires that 'ForEach<[TableColumn<Person, Never, Text, Text>], TableColumn<Person, Never, Text, Text>, some AccessibilityRotorContent>' conform to 'TableColumnContent'

Comment: I'm having the same problem and currently spending my evening investigating & researching a solution!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should know that UITableView has only one column.
So to help you with your problem, I can suggest you do these steps.

To have a tableView with multiple columns, create multiple UITableView, and put them together on the UI. (in a way that each tableView will play as one column!)
Now you have some tables that sit next to each other, and each table will be playing as one column.

Now problem is that each table has its own scroll.
As UITableview is derived from UIScrollview you can get the scroll amounts in the 'scrollViewDidScroll' delegate method.
On this delegate method, get the offset of the scrollView which is being scrolled, and assign that value to the other tableViews.

```
firstTableview.contentOffset = scrollview.contentOffset
```

Now all tableViews will be scrolling simultaneously with the same px height and feels that they play as a single TableView with multiple columns.

In the end, you want to make the user be able to reorder the table columns (actually you have to make tableViews to be able to change their position)
To achieve this, you have to create a UICollectionView that every cell of a collectionView will be one of your tableView. and then use some packages like 'Reorder' to make cells to be reordered.
(Reorder GitHub address: https://github.com/pikachu987/Reorder)

summary:

1. Create a UICollectionView with 3 cells. (cell.hight = yourPageHeigh, cell.width = yourPageWidth/3)
2. Use 'Reorder' package to make cells reorderable.
3. Each cell of the collectionView will contain one of your UITableView.
4. By using 'scrollViewDidScroll' method, make all tables scroll simultaneously.

Now you have a table that has some columns and columns can be reordered.

Comment: Thanks for your approach. Apple has introduced a new table type called "Table" in swiftUI 3.0 this summer. It is the SwiftUI equivalent of NSTableView and supports multi columns by its own.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/table  
My question is referencing to that. Creating multiple columns is not the problem to solve.

Comment: “First of all, you should know that UITableView has only one column.” The question is tagged macos, so the limitations of `UITableView` do not apply.

Answer (score 0):

In **macOS 14**, they've added a simple way of doing this with `TableColumnCustomization` -> [Apple's documentation article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tablecolumncustomization).

Example:

```swift
struct BugReportTable: View {
    @ObservedObject var dataModel: DataModel
    @Binding var selectedBugReports: Set<BugReport.ID>


    @SceneStorage("BugReportTableConfig")
    private var columnCustomization: TableColumnCustomization<BugReport>


    var body: some View {
        Table(dataModel.bugReports, selection: $selectedBugReports,
            sortOrder: $dataModel.sortOrder,
            columnCustomization: $columnCustomization
        ) {
            TableColumn("Title", value: \.title)
                .customizationID("title")
            TableColumn("ID", value: \.id) {
                Link("\($0.id)", destination: $0.url)
            }
            .customizationID("id")
            TableColumn("Number of Reports", value: \.duplicateCount) {
                Text($0.duplicateCount, format: .number)
            }
            .customizationID("duplicates")
        }
    }
}
```